# Is it possible to make ChartJS X-Axis an automatic day based on data and formatted to month?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a problem with my **line** chart at the moment. I currently get data in an array and am parsing it to the chart, this data works back from "Today".

What I was wondering, is if it is possible to make the x-axis display the month automatically based on the data given. For instance if the data has only 5 data points, that the x-axis will only show this month and a line chart with the datapoints given.

However, if the data has 144 data points in the array, the x-Axis displays the line across the 5(ish) months.

Is this possible? Currently I have this but it isn't displaying any data:

```
function populateLine(elementID, data) {

    let linectx = document.getElementById(elementID).getContext('2d');
    const _lineChart = new Chart(linectx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            // labels: ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'],
            datasets: [{
                data: data,
                borderWidth: 3
            }]
        },
        options: {
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    grid: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'month'
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    grid: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }
            },
            elements: {
                point: {
                    radius: 0
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, I have commented out the labels, as this does make the data display but instead of working backwards from today, it shows it from January across months based on data points, so if I have 5 data points it creates a line from Jan to Jun. But I am after a day based x-axis working backwards from today but displaying in months on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that comes across this, I ended up figuring it out using the luxon library.

```
let arrayOfDates = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    arrayOfDates.push(DateTime.local().minus({
        days: i
    }).toLocaleString({
        month: 'short',
        day: 'numeric'
    }));
}

arrayOfDates.reverse();
```

So what is happening here is I am creating an array of dates based on today and then subtracting a day for each point of data. I then reverse the array to match the direction of the data in the chart. I then use this array of dates as the labels.